# android.view.inflateexception binary xml file line

Tags: android, navigationview, inflate-exception

I am developing android application.In my application I have  used NavigationView .But it display InflateException in main xml file and application  gets closed.

my code is here

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" xmlns:app1="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.example.xpressownernew">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- The ActionBar -->
        <include
            layout="@layout/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <!-- The main content view -->
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/flContent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- The navigation drawer -->
    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nvView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:menu="@menu/drawer_view" 
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"

        />
</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Post your code with full Stace Trace.

Comment: need stacktrace, drawer_view.xml and your nav_header. xml.....

Comment: you only gave partial info. Post your logcat and other xml files

Answer (score 0):

If you are displaying any large image in any of that included layout, please  minimize  their resolution.